# Need help to remove punctuation and replace numbers for an nlp task

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, nlp

For example, I have a string:

```
sentence = ['cracked $300 million','she\'s resolutely, smitten ', 'that\'s creative [r]', 'the market ( knowledge check : prices up!']
```

I want to remove the punctuation and replace numbers with the '£' symbol.
I have tried this but can only replace one or the other when I try to run them both.
my code is below

```
import re
s =([re.sub(r'[!":$()[]\',]',' ', word) for word in sentence]) 

s= [([re.sub(r'\d+','£', word) for word in s])]
s)
```

I think the problem could be in the square brackets??
thank you!

Comment: [These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string) might also be relevant.

Comment: yes, I have fixed the regex yet the problem is about how to combine these two list comprehensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace some specific punctuation symbols with a space and any digit chunks with a `£` sign, you can use

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r'''[][!":$()',]|(\d+)''')
sentence = ['cracked $300 million','she\'s resolutely, smitten ', 'that\'s creative [r]', 'the market ( knowledge check : prices up!']
s = [rx.sub(lambda x: '£' if x.group(1) else ' ', word) for word in sentence] 
print(s) # => ['cracked  £ million', 'she s resolutely  smitten ', 'that s creative  r ', 'the market   knowledge check   prices up ']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cd72uF).

Note where `[]` are inside a character class: when `]` is at the start, it does not need to be escaped and `[` does not have to be escaped at all inside character classes. I also used a triple-quoted string literal, so you can use `"` and  `'` as is without extra escaping.

So, here, `[][!":$()',]|(\d+)` matches `]`, `[`, `!`, `"`, `:`, `$`, `(`, `)`, `'` or `,` or matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits. If Group 1 matched, the replacement is the euro sign, else, it is a space.

Comment: do you also know how to remove the " 's " from the word endings? for example, if I have another string containing "character's",  how can I remove 's so it is "character"?

Comment: @Bluetail See https://ideone.com/4XDxDQ, `rx = re.compile(r"""\b's\b|[][!":$()',]|(\d+)""")` might help.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i didn't see the second part of your request but you can to this for the number and the punctuation

```
sentence = ['cracked $300 million', 'she\'s resolutely, smitten ', 'that\'s creative [r]',
            'the market ( knowledge check : prices up!']
def replaceDigitAndPunctuation(newSentence):
    new_word = ""
    for char in newSentence:
        if char in string.digits:
            new_word += "£"
        elif char in string.punctuation:
            pass
        else:
            new_word += char
    return new_word


for i in range(len(sentence)):
    sentence[i] = replaceAllDigitInString(sentence[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your input and pattern:

```
>>> ([re.sub(r'[!":$()[]\',]',' ', word) for word in sentence]) 
['cracked $300 million', "she's resolutely, smitten ", "that's creative [r]", 'the market ( knowledge check : prices up!']
>>>
```

The reason is because `[!":$()[]` is being treated as a character group, and `\',]` is a literal pattern, i.e. the engine is looking for `',]` exactly.

With the closing bracket in the group escaped:

`\]`

```
>>> ([re.sub(r'[!":$()[\]\',]',' ', word) for word in sentence]) 
['cracked  300 million', 'she s resolutely  smitten ', 'that s creative  r ', 'the market   knowledge check   prices up ']
>>>
```

Edit:
If you're trying to stack multiple actions into a single list comprehension, then place your actions in a function and call the function:

```
def process_word(word):
  word = re.sub(r'[!":$()[\]\',]',' ', word)
  word = re.sub(r'\d+','£', word)
  return word
```

Results in:

```
>>> [process_word(word) for word in sentence]
['cracked  £ million', 'she s resolutely  smitten ', 'that s creative  r ', 'the market   knowledge check   prices up ']
```

Comment: yes, thank you!  I have also tried to remove " 's " at the end of the words like  in "that's" should become "that", but it did not quite work with the escape "\s' " symbol.

Comment: it gives an error, "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"  when I try process_word(sentence).

Comment: if `sentence` is a list of strings as in your example above, then you'll need to do the list comprehension to run the function on each string within the list.